Showing two expressions are same up to homotopy
Context: Let $X$ be a space, $x_0,x_1\in X$ and $p:[0,1]\to X$ be a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$. I am trying to show that for any continuous map $f:X\to Y$, the following
 commutes. Here, $p_*:[\alpha]\mapsto [p*\alpha*p^{-}]$ ($*$ is product of paths) is the group isomorphism induced by the path $p$, and similarly, $(f\circ p)_*$ is the group isomorphism induced by $f\circ p$. Also $f_*$ is the image of $f$ under $\pi_1$ functor. Throughout, $[\alpha]$ denotes path-homotopy class of some path $\alpha$ (in the appropriate space) and $p^{-}$ is the inverse path of the path $p$.
I know that I need to show, $[f\circ (p*\alpha*p^{-})]$ and $[(f\circ p)*(f\circ \alpha)*(f\circ p^{-})]$ are the same. I also know that for any map $f$ and any paths $p$, $q$, $f\circ (p*q)=(f\circ p)*(f\circ q)$.
Question: But since product of paths is associative only up to homotopy in general, I am unsure how to continue. I guess I can say something like,
$$[f\circ (p*\alpha*p^{-})]=[f\circ ((p*\alpha)*p^{-})]=[(f\circ (p*\alpha))*(f\circ p^{-})]=[(f\circ p)*(f\circ \alpha)*(f\circ p^{-})].$$
But I am not sure and I feel like I am sweeping things under the rug and crossing my fingers. So, I would like to ask help paraphrasing this in a clear and legal way.

"But since product of paths is associative only up to homotopy in general, I am unsure how to continue." ...but you're already working inside a homotopy class! If you really want to make things crystal clear you could say $f \circ (p * \alpha * p^{-}) \simeq f \circ ((p * \alpha) * p^{-}) = \ldots$ and mention that associativity is only up to (path) homotopy, but really this looks fine to me as-is.

In case you're curious, here is a synthetic proof of this fact in the language of homotopy type theory (more specifically in Cubical Agda). ap f is your $f_$ and conj p is your $p_$.

I think your worries are unfounded. If you really need to make things crystal clear, you could work "outside" the homotopy class, i.e. write
\begin{align}
    f \circ (p * \alpha * p^{-}) &\simeq f \circ ((p * \alpha) * p^{-}) \\
        &= (f \circ (p * \alpha)) * (f \circ p^{-}) \\
        &= ((f \circ p) * (f \circ \alpha)) * (f \circ p^{-}) \\
        &\simeq (f \circ p) * (f \circ \alpha) * (f \circ p^{-}) 
\end{align}
and explicitly say that the $\simeq$'s are justified by the homotopy associativity of path concatenation, but if this property is sufficiently well established with whoever is going to read this then I think what you have is already completely fine.

Okay, I might have been over-cautious as this is all new to me. Thank you :))
